# .htaccess : Internal server error 500 and removing .php extension conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple rewrite

`RewriteRule ^knowledge-center/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ knowledge-center-desc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]`

which was giving me error like

> [Mon Sep 19 15:35:21.351352 2016] [core:error] [pid 61226] [client 103.8.124.146:45569] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: `https://thewadhwagroup.com/knowledge-center`

Then I replaced the code for removing `.php` extension

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

   # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

with

```
#Remove .php extensions from php files :
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

And then I not faced `Internal server error`, everything now working fine but the problem is that, the code for removing `.php` extension is not working now (site [url](https://thewadhwagroup.com/)).
Please suggest me any solution that whats going wrong in my `.htaccess`.

**Update -** htaccess code

```html
# Leverage Browser Caching

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

 ExpiresActive On

 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"

 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"

 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"

 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"

 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"

 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"

 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"

 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"

 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"

 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

 <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">

  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"

 </filesmatch>

 <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">

  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"

 </filesmatch>

 <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">

  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"

 </filesmatch>

 <filesmatch "\.(js)$">

  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"

 </filesmatch>

</IfModule>

# mod_rewrite

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  # Enable mod_rewrite engine

  RewriteEngine on



  # WITH 'www.'

  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [NC]

  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www (link is external).thewadhwagroupprojects.in$1 [L,R=301]



  # WITOUT 'www.'



</IfModule>



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=15
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thewadhwagroup.com/residential-property/15/aquaria-grande? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>





<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 
 # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

 # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

</IfModule>



#--- URL FRIENDLY

# Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews



ErrorDocument 404 https://thewadhwagroup.com/page-not-found 

ErrorDocument 403 https://thewadhwagroup.com/page-not-found



RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /



#redirects old urls 

#Redirect 301 /about.php /about

Redirect 301 /corporate-profile.html /about

#Redirect 301 /knowledge-center.php /knowledge-center

Redirect 301 /knowledge-center/knowledge-center-loan.html /knowledge-center

Redirect 301 /knowledge-center/legal.html /knowledge-center

Redirect 301 /knowledge-center/knowledge-stamp-duty.html /knowledge-center

Redirect 301 /knowledge-center/knowledge-center-loan.html /knowledge-center

Redirect 301 /property-care.html /knowledge-center

Redirect 301 /knowledge-center-right-basics.php /knowledge-center-desc.php?id=1

Redirect 301 /knowledge-center-taking-loan.php /knowledge-center-desc.php?id=2

Redirect 301 /knowledge-center-after-loan.php /knowledge-center-desc.php?id=5

Redirect 301 /blog.php /knowledge-center-desc.php?id=6

#Redirect 301 /nri-corner.php /nri-corner

Redirect 301 /knowledge-center/nri-corner.html /nri-corner

Redirect 301 /nri.html /nri-corner

#Redirect 301 /career.php /career

Redirect 301 /hr-corner.html /career

#Redirect 301 /contact.php /contact

#Redirect 301 /contact-us.html /contact

Redirect 301 /site.php#india /site.php#india

Redirect 301 /contact-us/site-address.html /site.php#india

Redirect 301 /dubai-office.html /site.php

Redirect 301 /usa-office.html /site.php

#Redirect 301 /residential-properties.php /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /projects.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /residential-ongoing.html /residential-properties

#Redirect 301 /residential-properties.php?tp=completed /residential-properties?tp=completed

#Redirect 301 /commercial-properties.php /commercial-properties.php

#Redirect 301 /commercial-ongoing.html /commercial-properties.php

Redirect 301 /residential-property-mulund-atmosphere /residential-property/8/atmosphere

Redirect 301 /residential-property-matunga-w54 /residential-property/9/w-54

Redirect 301 /residential-property-ghatkoper-panorama /residential-property/19/panorama

Redirect 301 /residential-property-ghatkoper-panoroma /residential-property/19/panorama

Redirect 301 /apartments-in-ghatkopar-mumbai/panorama.html /residential-property/19/panorama

#Redirect 301 https://thewadhwagroup.com/residential-property/19/panoroma /residential-property/19/panorama

Redirect 301 /residential-property-ghatkoper-promenade /residential-property/20/promenade

Redirect 301 /promenade/index.html /residential-property/20/promenade

Redirect 301 /residential-property-goregaon-anmolfortune /residential-property/21/anmol-fortune

Redirect 301 /anmol-fortune/index.html /residential-property/21/anmol-fortune

Redirect 301 /residential-property-bandra-amarjivan /residential-property/11/amarjiwan

Redirect 301 /amarjivan/index.html /residential-property/11/amarjiwan

#Redirect 301 /residential-property-thane-solitaire.php /residential-property/21/anmol-fortune

#Redirect 301 /luxury-properties-in-thane-mumbai/solitaire.html /residential-property/21/anmol-fortune

Redirect 301 /residential-property-thane-platina /residential-property/13/platina

Redirect 301 /platina-residential/index.html /residential-property/13/platina

Redirect 301 /residential-property-thane-evergreen /residential-property/14/evergreen-heights

Redirect 301 /apartments-in-thane-mumbai/evergreen-heights.html /residential-property/14/evergreen-heights

Redirect 301 /residential-property-thane-courtyard /residential-property/18/wadhwa-courtyard

Redirect 301 /residential-property-borivali-aquariagrande /residential-property/15/aquaria-grande

Redirect 301 /Aquaria_grande/buy-property-in-mumbai-aquaria-grande.html /residential-property/15/aquaria-grande

#Redirect 301 /residential-property-andheri-thenest.php /

#Redirect 301 /the-nest/index.html /

Redirect 301 /residential-property-koregaonpark-marvelbasilo /residential-property/17/marvel-basilo

Redirect 301 /marvel-basilo/index.html /residential-property/17/marvel-basilo

Redirect 301 /residential-property-ghatkoper-theaddress /residential-property/10/the-address

Redirect 301 /The_address/Ghatkopar-properties-the-address.html /residential-property/10/the-address

Redirect 301 /commercial-property-bkc-thecapital /commercial-property/22/the-capital

Redirect 301 /The_Capital/commercial-properties-in-bkc-the-capital.html /commercial-property/22/the-capital

Redirect 301 /commercial-property-bkc-platina-comm /commercial-property/24/platina

Redirect 301 /Platina/commercial-office-space-in-bkc-Platina.html /commercial-property/24/platina

Redirect 301 /commercial-property-andheri-glenmark /commercial-property/26/glenmark

Redirect 301 /glenmark/index.html /commercial-property/26/glenmark

Redirect 301 /commercial-property-bkc-trade-center /commercial-property/25/trade-center



Redirect 301 /residential-property/51/landmark-prabhadevi http://www.landmarkprabhadevi.com/

Redirect 301 /guides/upcoming-residential-prabhadevi.html http://www.landmarkprabhadevi.com/

Redirect 301 /guides/living-in-prabhadevi.html http://www.landmarkprabhadevi.com/



Redirect 301 /Solitaier/new-flatsfor-sale-in-mumbai-solitaire.html /residential-property/12/solitaire

Redirect 301 /The_address/gallery.html /residential-property/10/the-address

Redirect 301 /Imperial_hights/residential-projects-in-mumbai-imperial-heights.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /Imperial_hights/residential-projects-in-mumbai-imperial-heights.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /Anmol_prestige/property-for-sale-in-mumbai-anmol-prestige.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /Anmol_prestige/property-for-sale-in-mumbai-anmol-prestige.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /Imperial_hights/luxurt-apartments-in-mumbai-imperial-heights.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /the-nest/gallery.html /residential-property/16/the-nest

Redirect 301 /apartments-in-ghatkopar-mumbai/panorama/lifestyle-showcase.html /residential-property/19/panorama

Redirect 301 /our_presence.html /about

Redirect 301 /res_aquaria_grande.html /residential-property/15/aquaria-grande

Redirect 301 /luxury-properties-in-thane-mumbai/solitaire/overview.html /residential-property/12/solitaire

Redirect 301 /apartments-in-thane-mumbai/evergreen-heights/overview.html /residential-property/14/evergreen-heights

Redirect 301 /residential-property-andheri-thenest /residential-property/16/the-nest

Redirect 301 /residential-property-thane-solitaire /residential-property/12/solitaire

Redirect 301 /the-nest/index.html /residential-property/16/the-nest

Redirect 301 /apartments-in-thane-mumbai/evergreen-heights/overview.html /residential-property/14/evergreen-heights

Redirect 301 /commercial-ongoing.html /commercial-properties.php

Redirect 301 /luxury-properties-in-thane-mumbai/solitaire.html /residential-property/12/solitaire

Redirect 301 /the-nest/index.html /residential-property/16/the-nest

Redirect 301 /Imperial_hights/gallery.html /

Redirect 301 /imperial-pics/gallery/status_4-big.jpg /

Redirect 301 /imperial-pics/gallery/status_5-big.jpg /

Redirect 301 /Imperial_hights/gallery.html /

Redirect 301 /imperial-pics/gallery/status_4-big.jpg /

Redirect 301 /imperial-pics/gallery/status_5-big.jpg /

Redirect 301 /res_imperial_heights.html /

Redirect 301 /res_imperial_heights.html /

Redirect 301 /res_solitaire.html /residential-property/12/solitaire

Redirect 301 /com_the_capital.html /commercial-property/22/the-capital

#Redirect 301 /luxury-properties-in-thane-mumbai/solitaire.html /residential-property/12/solitaire

Redirect 301 /hospitality.html /

Redirect 301 /Aquaria_grande/gallery.html /residential-property/15/aquaria-grande

Redirect 301 /com_c-66.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /Anmol_pride/new-properties-in-mumbai-anmol-pride.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 /apartments-in-ghatkopar-mumbai/panorama /residential-property/19/panorama

Redirect 301 /res_palm_beach.html /residential-properties

Redirect 301 http://www.thewadhwagroup.com/apartments-in-ghatkopar-mumbai/panorama https://thewadhwagroup.com/residential-properties/19/panorama



Redirect 301 /residential-property/8/index /residential-property/8/atmosphere
Redirect 301 /residential-property/8/residential-properties /residential-property/8/atmosphere


Redirect 301 /index / 

Redirect 301 /residential-property/15/residential-properties /residential-property/15/aquaria-grande
Redirect 301 /residential-property/15/index /residential-property/15/aquaria-grande

Redirect 301 /residential-property-desc /residential-properties

#vilas .htaccess

RewriteRule ^residential-property-new/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ residential-property-desc-new.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^commercial-property-new/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ commercial-property-desc-new.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

#RewriteRule ^knowledge-center/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ knowledge-center-desc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^knowledge-center/(\d+)(?:/.*)?$ knowledge-center-desc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

#http to https

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



#www to non www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroup\.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thewadhwagroup.com/$1 [L,R=301]



#Remove .php extensions from php files :

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 



#RewriteRule ^knowledge-center/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ knowledge-center-desc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]



RewriteRule ^residential-property/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ residential-property-desc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^commercial-property/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ commercial-property-desc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]



#--- END URL FRIENDLY



RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/" [R=301,L]



# sunday mobility htaccess to dynamic page

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^residential\-property\-matunga\-w54\.php$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-desc\.php?id=9" [R=302,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^corporate\-profile\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/about\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^projects\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-properties\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^residential\-ongoing\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-properties\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^commercial\-ongoing\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/commercial\-properties\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^nri\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/nri\-corner\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^knowledge\-center\/nri\-corner.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/nri\-corner\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^hr\-corner\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/career\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^contact\-us\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/contact\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^contact\-us\/site\-address\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/site\.php\#india" [R=301,NE,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^dubai\-office\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/site\.php\#dubai" [R=301,NE,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^usa\-office\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/site\.php\#usa" [R=301,NE,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^press\-media\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/press\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^knowledge\-center\/legal\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/knowledge\-center\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^knowledge\-center\/knowledge\-stamp\-duty\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/knowledge\-center\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^knowledge\-center\/knowledge\-center\-loan\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/knowledge\-center\-taking\-loan\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^property\-care\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/knowledge\-center\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^apartments\-in\-thane\-mumbai\/evergreen\-heights\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-thane\-evergreen\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^platina\-residential\/index\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-thane\-platina\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^apartments\-in\-ghatkopar\-mumbai\/panorama\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-ghatkoper\-panorama\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^luxury\-properties\-in\-thane\-mumbai\/solitaire\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-thane\-solitaire\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^The_address\/Ghatkopar\-properties\-the\-address\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-ghatkoper\-theaddress\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^the\-nest\/index\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-andheri\-thenest\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^Aquaria_grande\/buy\-property\-in\-mumbai\-aquaria\-grande\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-borivali\-aquariagrande\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^amarjivan\/index\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-bandra\-amarjivan\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^anmol\-fortune\/index\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-goregaon\-anmolfortune\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^promenade\/index\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-ghatkoper\-promenade\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^marvel\-basilo\/index\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/residential\-property\-koregaonpark\-marvelbasilo\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^The_Capital\/commercial\-properties\-in\-bkc\-the\-capital\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/commercial\-property\-bkc\-thecapital\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^Platina\/commercial\-office\-space\-in\-bkc\-Platina\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/commercial\-property\-bkc\-platina\-comm\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^vishwaroop_it_park\/overview\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/itpark\-vashi\-vishwaroop\.php" [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thewadhwagroupprojects\.in$

RewriteRule ^glenmark\/index\.html$ "http\:\/\/thewadhwagroupprojects\.in\/commercial\-property\-andheri\-glenmark\.php" [R=301,L]



# Enable Compression

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>

  mod_gzip_on Yes

  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes

  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$

  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$

  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*

  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*

  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*

  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^knowledge-center/(\d+)(?:/.*)?$ knowledge-center-desc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I've added your code, `.php` extension in removed but now I'm getting Internal server error at this https://thewadhwagroup.com/knowledge-center/1/getting-basics-right . Please see my edited question.

Comment: I didn't understood, explain some more please

Comment: Move down the rule with comment `# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php` after all other rules in your htaccess

Comment: Yes..! Its working now, can you please explain what are those issues which I'd with my `.htaccess`.

Comment: Just a generic guideline to keep to keep all redirect and specific rewrites at top and generic catch-all type rules at the bottom.